# Angular2 @types/sharepoint/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: sharepoint, angular, typescript, sharepoint-2013, typescript-typings

I'm using Angular 2 in SharePoint

I'm building a service that needs to call Sharepoint via csom and rest and I have run into trouble with the typing for Sharepoint 2013

I have run `npm install @types/sharepoint --save-dev` and am now trying to reference the sharepoint types in my TypeScript code

when I import `import * as sharepoint  from 'sharepoint';` I get the error `@types/sharepoint/index.d.ts' is not a module`

I don't know how to fix this.

On a side note, doing the exact same thing with the D3 library throws no error i.e.

`npm install @types/d3 --save-dev`

`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

works just fine

**EDIT - 11 May 2018**

At the top of your file add these to access any ambient variables

`declare var SP: any
declare var _spPageContextInfo: any`

Comment: hey peter, how using this typings also, how can i use the _spPageContextInfo globally in my components?

Comment: @KevinRodriguez see EDIT 11/5/2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not import typings.

If you can import from 'd3' without any compilation errors then your library folder must have a reference to 'd3' notably `./node_modules/d3`.

Some Info on typings is that it guides the compiler as it generates JavaScript files. Additionally, it gives you type checking at design which is a huge benefit to javascript.

you can check if there are modules for sharepoint Here is what i found : https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/sharepoint

Comment: so they're just an ambient thing?

Comment: In a sense they have always been.

Here is some info : Ambient declarations is a promise that you are making with the compiler. If these do not exist at runtime and you try to use them, things will break without warning.

Read more here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html